# VisiCalc Java Project

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a VisiCalc style project, but I'm having one problem. I'm supposed to be able to reference a cell, an example input would be `A1 = ( 2 + 3 )`
and then I would reference `A1` by going `A2 = ( A1 + 2 )` or something like that.
I don't know where to start, but my code is below, any help is greatly appreciated.
BTW if you do start using the code there should be 6 classes.

**VisiCalc.class**

```
public class VisiCalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int MAX_ROWS = 10; //rows
        final int MAX_COLS = 7; //columns
        final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 12;//width of cell

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Grid grid = new Grid(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS, DISPLAY_WIDTH);
        System.out.println("Welcome to VisiCalc!");
        System.out.println();
        String input = "";

        //allow user to enter multiple commands
        while(!input.equals("quit"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a command: ");
            input = console.nextLine();
            if(input.equals("print"))
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(grid);
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if(input.equals("quit"))
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Farewell!");
            }
            else if(input.equals(""))
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                String Reference = "";//next few lines are Mr.Gilbrough's code
                int equals = input.indexOf(" = ");
                if(equals < 0)
                {
                    Reference = input.toUpperCase();
                    input = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    Reference = input.substring(0, equals).toUpperCase();
                    input = input.substring(equals + 3);
                }
                if(Helpers.isValidCell(Reference, MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS))
                {
                    if(input.length() > 0)
                    {
                        if(!grid.setCell(Reference, input))
                        {
                            System.out.println("please enter a valid command");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        input = grid.getCell(Reference);
                        System.out.print(Reference + " = ");
                        if(input.equals(""))
                        {
                            System.out.print("please enter a valid command");
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.print(input);
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Grid.class**

```
public class Grid
{
    private int max_rows;
    private int max_cols; // makes the constructors
    private int display_width;
    private Cell[][] spreadsheet;

    //creates the grid class
    public Grid(int row, int col, int width)
    {
        display_width = width;
        max_rows = row;
        max_cols = col;
        spreadsheet = new Cell[row + 1][col + 1];
        setSheet();
        setHead();
    }

    //heading
    public void setHead()
    {
        for(int col = 1; col <= max_cols; col++)
        {
            spreadsheet[0][col] = new Cell(Helpers.getColLetter(col));
        }
        for(int row = 1; row <= max_rows; row++)
        {
            spreadsheet[row][0] = new Cell("" + row);
        }
    }

    public void setSheet()
    {
        for(int col = 0; col <= max_cols; col++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row <= max_rows; row++)
            {
                spreadsheet[row][col] = new Cell();
            }
        }
    }

    // print
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        for(int row = 0; row <= max_rows; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col <= max_cols; col++)
            {
                output += center(spreadsheet[row][col].toString());
                if(col < max_cols)
                {
                    output += "|";
                }
            }
            output += "\n";
            if(row < max_rows)
            {
                output += lines();
            }
        }
        return output;
    }


    private String center(String contents)
    {
        if(contents.length() > display_width)
        {
            return contents.substring(0, display_width - 1) + ">";
        }
        int buffer = display_width - contents.length();
        int left = buffer / 2;
        int right = display_width - contents.length() - left;
        return spacing(left, " ") + contents + spacing(right, " ");
    }

    //Mr.Gilbrough's method
    private String spacing(int width, String spacer)
    {
        String space = "";
        for(int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
        {
            space += spacer;
        }
        return space;
    }

    //Creates the lines between each row
    private String lines()
    {
        String line = "";
        for(int a = 0; a <= max_cols; a++)
        {
            line += spacing(display_width, "-");
            if(a < max_cols)
            {
                line += "+";
            }
        }
        return line + "\n";
    }

    //Mr.Gilbrough's method
    public boolean setCell(String cellRef, String con)
    {
        int col = Helpers.getColIndexFromString(cellRef);
        int row = Helpers.getRowIndexFromString(cellRef);
        if(con.charAt(0) == '"')
        {
            spreadsheet[row][col] = new Cell(con);
            return true;
        }
        else if(con.charAt(0) == '(')
        {
            spreadsheet[row][col] = new FormulaCell(con);
            return true;
        }
        double num = 0;
        try
        {
            num = Double.parseDouble(con);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        spreadsheet[row][col] = new DoubleCell(num);
        return true;
    }

    //Mr.Gilbrough's method
    public String getCell(String cellRef)
    {
        int col = Helpers.getColIndexFromString(cellRef);
        int row = Helpers.getRowIndexFromString(cellRef);
        return spreadsheet[row][col].getCon();

    }
}
```

**Cell.class**

```
public class Cell
{
    private String contents;

    public Cell(String data)
    {
        contents = data;
    }

    public Cell()
    {
        this("");
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if(contents.length() > 2)
        {
            return contents.substring(1, contents.length() - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return contents;
        }
    }

    public String getCon()
    {
        return contents;
    }
}
```

**FormulaCell.class**

```
//extends to use stuff from cell and to set cell
public class FormulaCell extends Cell
{
    private String contents;

    public FormulaCell(String data)
    {
        contents = data;
    }

    public FormulaCell()
    {
        this("");
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + calc();
    }

    public String getCon()
    {
        return contents;
    }

    public double getNumber(String token)
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(token);
    }

    public double calc()
    {
        Scanner tokens = new Scanner(contents);
        double result = 0;
        String op = "";
        boolean start = true;
        while(tokens.hasNext())
        {
            String token = tokens.next();
            if(token.equals("(") || token.equals(")"))
            {
                //nothing
            }
            else if(ifNumber(token))
            {
                double number = getNumber(token);
                if(op.equals(""))
                {
                    result = number;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(op.equals("+"))
                    {
                        result = result + number;
                    }
                    else if(op.equals("-"))
                    {
                        result = result - number;
                    }
                    else if(op.equals("*"))
                    {
                        result = result * number;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = result / number;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                op = token;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //this is to throw exception
    public boolean ifNumber(String token)
    {
        double number = 0;
        try
        {
            number = Double.parseDouble(token);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Helpers.class**

```
//Evan Zverev
public class Helpers
{
    // returns column letter where A = first column
    public static String getColLetter(int col)
    {
        return "" + (char) ('A' + col - 1);
    }

    // returns column index where 1 = first column
    public static int getColIndex(char col)
    {
        return col - 'A' + 1;
    }

    // returns true/false if the given character is a valid column given the max
    public static boolean isValidCol(int col, int maxCol)
    {
        return col > 0 && col <= maxCol;
    }

    // returns true/false if the given row is a valid row given the max
    public static boolean isValidRow(int row, int maxRow)
    {
        return row > 0 && row <= maxRow;
    }

    // take in a cell ID and return the column index (ie: C4 will return 3)
    public static int getColIndexFromString(String cellID)
    {
        char col = cellID.charAt(0);
        return getColIndex(col);
    }

    // take in a cell ID such as C4 and return the row index (ie: C4 will return 4)
    public static int getRowIndexFromString(String cellID)
    {
        String row = cellID.substring(1);
        return Integer.parseInt(row);
    }

    // take in a cell ID and a max row/col and return true/false if the cell is valid
    public static boolean isValidCell(String cellID, int maxRows, int maxCols)
    {
        int colIndex = getColIndexFromString(cellID);
        int rowIndex = -1;
        try
        {
            rowIndex = getRowIndexFromString(cellID);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return isValidCol(colIndex, maxCols) && isValidRow(rowIndex, maxRows);
    }
}
```